# Correct way to find non-parametric confidence intervals using bootstrap

Tags: r, time-series, nonparametric, trend

I'm using a bootstrap method to find the 95% confidence interval for Sen's slope, but I'm not sure if my methodology is correct. My steps are as follows:

```
#create data.frame
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,
             y = rnorm(100))

#Sen's slope

slope <- zyp.sen(y~x,data = df)
slope <- slope$coef[1] + slope$coef[2]*df$x

#bootstrap the tau statistic of zyp.trend.vector (pre-whitening step)

pw_tau_func <- function(z) zyp.trend.vector(z, method = "yuepilon")[5]
boot.out <- tsboot(df$y, pw_tau_func, R=999, l=5, sim="fixed")

#find confidence intervals from boot object using boot.ci

ci_upr <- boot.ci(boot.out, type="norm")$normal[3]
ci_upr <- slope + abs(ci_upr)
ci_lwr <- boot.ci(boot.out, type="norm")$normal[2]
ci_lwr <- slope - abs(ci_lwr)

#plot output

plot(slope, type = "l", ylab = "Simulated Data", ylim = c(-1,1))
points(ci_upr, col = "red")
points(ci_lwr, col = "red")
```

Is bootstrapping the tau statistic the correct method for generating confidence intervals? I've seen conflicting information around the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mann-Kendall test for trend and Thiel-Sen slope estimate are two different things. The MK test tests the null hypothesis of no trend, whereas the Sen's slope estimate the trend's magnitude. In the above example I was bootstrapping the tau statistic, and not Sen's slope. To find the 95% CI for Sen's slope:

```
beta <- function(df) zyp.sen(y~x, df)$coefficients[2]
boot.out <- tsboot(df, beta, R = 250, l = 5, sim = "fixed")
ci_lwr_mk <- boot.ci(boot.out, conf = 0.95, type = "norm")$normal[[2]]
ci_upr_mk <- boot.ci(boot.out, conf = 0.95, type = "norm")$normal[[3]]
```